# Create a list of objects using map keys and values as constructor parameters

Tags: java, object, dictionary

```
NavigableMap<String, String> map; // this map contains e.g. 10 elements
MyObject foo = new MyObject("string as 1st parameter", "and as 2nd parameter");
```

Now I want to do something like this:

```
List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
objects.addAll(forEach(map) {new MyObject(map.key, map.value)});
```

I know, I could iterate over the map:

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
  objects.add(new MyObject(key, map.get(key)));
}
```

My question is, whether this is possible in some other more funky way :) (within JAVA 7)

Comment: Use of [entrySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) will certainly improve this code

Comment: Not much more funky, but yet a little: Use the [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) to iterate over your map.

Comment: Java is not so funky when it comes to iterations. Add Groovy support to your application, it's groovy when it comes to such functionality. :)

Comment: An obvious way is to implement `forEach` method that will take map and return `Collection<MyObject>`. It's not really funky, though. AFAIK there are no syntactic sugar to easily handle collections in java sdk. You might want to look into google collections or `commons-collections`

Comment: Sorry, the example above should only show, that a manual iteration was not my intent. Btw: is it significantly slower when I iterate over keys and then always get the values, compared to iterating over the entries?

Comment: @radio My point was that `entrySet` fits better in this situation (makes the code clearer). To estimate performance gain you need some field tests. It depends on map implementation, number of elements, number of threads, etc. etc.

Comment: There is no funky way and there are a million funky ways (I am not being sarcastic). I think you have the intuition covered-- you feel that the solution to your problem can be approached in a more elegant fashion, perhaps it's the underlying data structure. 

Someone may type in a cool answer thats full of syntactic sugar and you may accept but I think the deeper answer is else where -- perhaps it lies in understanding why you chose those data structures -- does it lend itself well to execute your algorithm?

Comment: Ok, I see, with java it is not possible, thanks for your comments